# Dynamic editing and running quickly apps

Tags: python, gtk, quickly, glade

Is there a possibility of viewing the `app changes` dynamically as i `edit` the code or the interface(in glade).

I want to basically edit and view the changes in the app on the fly, `without restarting` the app again.

Comment: anyone having a workflow like this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, this cannot be done.